# Dynamically Create a New Column in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, assign

I am trying to improve my code and avoid repeating lines to import multiple csvs with same name structure:

```
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210301 <- read.csv("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210301.csv", header = T)
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210301$WeekDate <- "2021-03-01"
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210308 <- read.csv("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210308.csv", header = T)
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210308$WeekDate <- "2021-03-08"
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210315 <- read.csv("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210315.csv", header = T)
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210315$WeekDate <- "2021-03-15"
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210322 <- read.csv("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210322.csv", header = T)
iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_20210322$WeekDate <- "2021-03-22"
```

I managed to implement it to read the csv but I don't know how to as well insert the part where I create a new column  `WeekDate` to the data frame and where I give it the date value.

```
week_date_list <- c("20210301", "20210308", "20210315", "20210322" )

for(week_date in week_date_list){
  
  assign(paste0("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_", week_date), read.csv(paste0("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_", week_date, ".csv"), header = T))
         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global env.  This could be easily done by storing in a `list` (used `R 4.1.0` for lambda (`\(week_date)`) or use `function(week_date)`

```
lst1 <- lapply(week_date_list, \(week_date) {
          tmp <- read.csv(paste0("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_", 
                            week_date, ".csv"), header = TRUE)
          tmp$WeekDate <- as.Date(week_date, format = "%Y%m%d")
          tmp
   })
```

In the OP's `for` loop

```
for(week_date in week_date_list){
  tmp <- read.csv(paste0("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_", week_date, ".csv"),
             header = TRUE)
   tmp$WeekDate <- as.Date(week_date, format = "%Y%m%d")
   assign(paste0("iOS_Weekly_Active_Users_", week_date), tmp)
 }
```